# Generic type as parameter in Java Method

Tags: java, generics, methods

Do you think it is possible to create something similar to this?

```
private ArrayList increaseSizeArray(ArrayList array_test, GenericClass) {
    array_test.add(new GenericObject()); // instance of GenericClass
    return array_test;
}
```

Answer (score 109, accepted):

Yes, you can.

```
private static <T> List<T> pushBack(List<T> list, Class<T> typeKey) throws Exception {
    list.add(typeKey.getConstructor().newInstance());
    return list;
}
```

Usage example:

```
List<String> strings = new ArrayList<String>();
pushBack(strings, String.class);
```

Comment: How do you call that method? I don't know what Class<T> typekey should be. I can't find anything about it. If you have any reading advice, it will be welcome. Thank you for your response!

Comment: @Pierre: Just added a usage example. Basically, if you take a class name (`String` in this case) and add `.class` after it, you have a type key (class object) for that class. `String.class` has type `Class<String>`.

Comment: I just used it like this:  static <T> List<T> pushBack(List<T> list, Class typeKey, int size) and it worked. Thank you, you helped me a lot. Avoiding copy/paste code is always a joy.

Comment: Why <T> is used just before return type ? I am also doing the same thing but i want to know the actual usage of <T>. Thanks in advance.

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html introduces the construct of `static <T> void method(...)`

Comment: Correction... https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/methods.html actually introduces the syntax (the above link I provided does not).

Answer (score 13):

Old question but I would imagine this is the preferred way of doing it in java8+

```
public <T> ArrayList<T> dynamicAdd(ArrayList<T> list, Supplier<T> supplier) {
  list.add(supplier.get());
  return list;
}
```

and it could be used like this:

```
AtomicInteger counter = ...;
ArrayList<Integer> list = ...;

dynamicAdd(list, counter::incrementAndGet);
```

this will add a number to the list, getting the value from AtomicInteger's `incrementAndGet` method

Also possible to use constructors as method references like this: `MyType::new`

Answer (score 3):

simple solution!

```
private <GenericType> ArrayList increaseSizeArray(ArrayList array_test, GenericType genericObject)
{
    array_test.add(new genericObject());
    return ArrayList;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You can do so, and [this page in Oracle's docs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/extra/generics/methods.html) show you how

```
// Example of a void method
<T> void doSomething(T someT) {
  // Do something with variable
  System.out.println(someT.toString());
}

// Example of a method that returns the same generic type passed in.
<T> T getSomeT(T someT) {
  return someT;
}
```